# What is the difference between these sentences including present participle?

Tags: parts-of-speech, participles, present-participles, participle-clauses, participial-adjectives

What is the difference between these sentences including present participle?

> The running car has no batteries.
>   The car (which is) running has no batteries.

Comment: It would help if you explained what these sentences are supposed to mean. Is a running car a particular type of car, like a sports car? A car with the engine running? A car that is moving? Are they electric cars like a Tesla? Radio- controlled model cars?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Is the second sentence "The car running has not batteries." or "The car which is running has no batteries."? If it's the first one, it's grammatically incorrect; adjectives should precede nouns, so "car running" is incorrect, and should be corrected to "running car", as in your other version of sentence.

But if your question is about "The car which is running", then the difference is really just a stylistic one; "the running car" and "the car which is running" both *mean* the same thing, but some speakers or writers may prefer the sound of one over the other.

Personally, I think both phrasings are actually a bit awkward, because "running car" is not a phrasing I hear very often; if I needed to refer to a running car, depending on context, I might actually say "the car *that* is running", especially if I'm picking one car out of a row of several cars, e.g. "There are three cars out front; the car that is running has no batteries."

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ken Bellows.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I often come across the sentences like I mentioned above.

For instance, 
The spreading news is open and accessible to anyone.
The news (that is) spreading is open and accessible to anyone.

In this case, I suppose, the author is talking about a piece of news which is being spread.

And I would like to know if there is a difference between the sentences, or they carry the same meaning.

Your answers are much appreciated.